# Integrating Excel Sheet in PHP (much simple)

Tags: php, excel

I'm searching for a way to read some cells from an Excel Sheet from my PHP page.
I've just downloaded PHPExcelReader 2.2 and PHPExcel180 and I'm reading the source code and documentation, but I'm a newbie.
With the first library I can dump the entire document, including the layout (cell and font color and style), thanks to the example in the package, but I'm still reading to understand.

This is the situation:
- In the sheet there is a first row, where A1, B1 and C1 are filled with "labels".
- After each label, follow some datas in that 3 columns.

This is what I need:
- I need to search for a label in the first row. I have to find "X" in the first row and obtain the column where it's placed.
- More generically, I need to find "X" in the document, and obtain the position (row/column) where it is.
- And, last but not the least, I want to do the inverse thing: knowing the coord (eg.: G6) I want to know the content of the cell.

I don't need layout, colors, borders or anything else. Only the raw value.
Can someone post a link with a sample code?
I need a well done library more than the "pseudocode", I have clear in mind what to do. I don't know what library choose.

EDIT: it seems that PHPExcel180 is more well documented than PHPExcelReader. Example 28 is just about iterator. Some modifications and it did the trick.

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation or looked at the examples for either of these libraries?

Comment: Basically, iterate over the cells in the first row of the spreadsheet, retrieving the value for that cell, and compare it with the value that you're looking for

Comment: I looked much superficially because now I'm busy with my really work (which doesn't include PHP). With PHPExcelReader I didn't understand anything it is very simple and seems to be only able to do the entire dump of the document, so I'll have to put my hands in the source code. PHPExcel instead has a too long documentation.
I'm searching for something already usable, and with documentation/tutorial well done. Do you know something?

Comment: I'm searching for a tested library, not for code.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of searching, testing and reading about libraries, I choose PHPExcel.
It seems to be more well documented than PHPExcelReader. Example 28 is just about iterator. Some modifications and it did the trick.